# I want to make a script that recognises even numbers

Tags: python

I want to make a script that asks the user to enter any amount of numbers, separated by a comma and then return which ones of them are even. 
I've managed to create a script that does it just with one number. But now I'm trying to get it to do an unlimited amount of numbers and print only the even ones

here is what I have so far:

```
y = raw_input ('please enter a list of numbers separated by commas\n').split(',')
z = [int(x.strip()) for x in y]
len(z)
for i in len(z):
    if i%2 == 0:
        print i,'is even'
        i == i+1
    else:
        i == i+1
```

I know its the loop that's the problem. I'm not sure how to make the loop go through my list and perform the modulus operator to each of the numbers in the list.

Comment: What do you think the statement `len(z)` is accomplishing?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque How is this question related to that one? There's no `for` loop there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use bitwise operator to test if the last bit is 0 or not

```
>>> 2 & 1
0
>>> 3 & 1
1
>>> 5&1
1
>>> 6&1
0
```

and you can do something like this

```
# suppose your list is this
lis1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
filter(lambda x: x&1 == 0, lis1)
# output -- [2,4,6,8]
```

Answer (score 2):

`z` is your list; just iterate over it.

```
y = raw_input('...').split(',')
z = [int(x) for x in y]   # int() is smart enough to deal with extra whitespace
for i in z:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print i, 'is even'
```

There's no need to increment `i` (also, `i = i + 1`, not `i == i + 1`), as `i` is set to a new value from `z` each time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, it worked! and i now understand what i was doing wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

So, a better way to do this would be:

```
z = [int(x) for x in y if int(x)%2 == 0]
```

Now your list has only the even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your for loop incorrectly.  Try the following

```
for i in z:
  if i % 2 == 0:
    print i,'is even'
```

Not sure what your intention was with incrementing `i`, but I left it out for simplicity's sake...

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to iterate over an integer which is not valid. Try this:

```
y = raw_input ('please enter a list of numbers separated by commas\n').split(',')
z = [int(x.strip()) for x in y]
for i in z:
    if i%2 == 0:
        print i,'is even'
```

The for loop now iterates over the *elements* in the list, instead of attempting to iterate over its length. This is the most Pythonic way to iterate over the elements in a sequence. For comparison, you can use indexing like this:

```
for i in range(len(z)):
    if z[i]%2 == 0:
        print i,'is even'
```

but the former is preferred, and more efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

change your for statement to `for i in z`

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a generator function instead. Here is an example. From your code, it seems like you're using Python2.x. If this is not the case, and you are using Python3.x, you can use the build-in `map` function instead of `itertools.imap`

```
from itertools import imap

def even_from_str(s):
    for even in imap(lambda x: x%2 == 0, imap(int, s.split(',')):
        yield even

nums = raw_input('please enter a list of numbers separated by commas\n')
print list(even_from_str(nums))
```